# How to store all outgoing mails from postfix in DB (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, email, centos, postfix

I have a postfix setup for my web server and I want to store every outgoing email from the server to a database. Does any one know how I can achieve this. FYI I just use this server to send emails and I use google Apps to receive emails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youre going to have to do several things

1. Use the [always_bcc](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#always_bcc) setting to fork a copy of the emails to an alternate destination (what you use really doesnt matter, this is just for item #3 below)
2. Set up a [pipe](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html) transport in your master.cf file which will receive the emails and store them in the database. You are going to have to write this utility/script yourself.
3. Use [transport_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#transport_maps) to redirect mail for that always_bcc address to the transport you defined in master.cf